How to retrieve the update authority info with spl-token or metaplex foundation lib using javascript?
My main question is how to retrieve the update authority information (mint address as string) given a token address with the @solana/spl-token or @metaplex-foundation/js library using JavaScript.
I have searched through Stackoverflow, Stack Exchange, and the respective GitHub repositories from Solana Labs and the Metaplex Foundation to find code examples.
Any advice, code example, or documentation I overlooked is highly appreciated!

The spl Token lib cannot provide the update authority since it is related to metaplex token metadata.
Please be aware that @metaplex-foundation/js is very outdated, deprecated and absolutely not recommended to use. Nowadays one would use umi (which is a metaplex made js Framework to access that data.
import { fetchDigitalAsset } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const asset = await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, mint)
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch
If you absolutely need to use @metaplex-foundation/js you can as far as I remember use findByMint https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js?tab=readme-ov-file#findByMint

thank you! that helped a lot
